# react-redux container gets the new props but children do not update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

My redux store is being update successfully. The container has the new props however the children still have the old one.

This kind of things as I googled mostly happen from mutations. But as much I can see I don't have any mutations.

So here is my container component `Chat.jsx`

```
import '../../../assets/stylesheets/styles.scss'

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import setContactId from '../redux/actions/setContactId'
import setChat from '../redux/actions/setChat'
import submitEmail from '../redux/actions/submitEmail'
import submitMessage from '../redux/actions/submitMessage'

import ddp from '../../ddp'

import Cookies from 'js-cookie'

import View from './views/View'
import Icon from './Icon'

class Chat extends Component {
  componentDidMount () {
    this.setContactIdFromCookies()
  }

  setContactIdFromCookies = () => {
    const contactId = Cookies.get('b2cContactId')
    if (contactId) this.props.setContactId(contactId)
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps = (nextProps) => {
    if (!nextProps.contactId) return
    this.getChat(nextProps.contactId)
  }

  getChat = async (contactId) => {
    console.log('getChat', contactId)
    await ddp.subscribe('Chats', {contactId})
    const chatCollection = ddp.getCollection('Chats')
    console.log('chatCollection', chatCollection)
    this.props.setChat(this.extractChatFromCollection(chatCollection))
    ddp.watch('Chats', (changedDoc, message) => {
      console.log('Chats collection item changed', changedDoc, message)
      const chatCollection = ddp.getCollection('Chats')
      this.props.setChat(this.extractChatFromCollection(chatCollection))
    })
  }

  extractChatFromCollection = collection => {
    const chatId = Object.keys(collection)[0]
    const chat = collection[chatId]
    chat._id = chatId
    return chat
  }

  emailInputRef = null

  onEmailSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log('email', this.emailInputRef.value,)

    this.props.submitEmail({
       email: this.emailInputRef.value,
       convertedPage: window.location.href,
       projectId: this.props.projectId,
       visitSessionId: this.props.visitSessionId
     })
  }

  render () {
    if (!this.props.chat._id) return null
    return (
      <div>
        <View
          visitSessionId={this.props.visitSessionId}
          defaultAdminUserName='default defaultAdminUserName'
          contactName='default contactName'
          supportName='default supportName'
          messages={this.props.chat.messages}
          onSend={this.props.submitMessage}
         />
        <Icon />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

// DONE: REDUX
// DONE: Meteor client???
// TODO: Components

Chat = connect(state => ({
  contactId: state.contactId,
  chat: state.chat
}), { setContactId, setChat, submitEmail, submitMessage })(Chat)

export default Chat
```

Here is the `View.jsx`

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

import Messages from './Messages'
import Input from './Input'

const View = props => <div id='chat-container'>
  <div className='chat-box' style={{
    maxWidth: '350px',
    height: '469px',
    background: 'gainsboro',
    WebkitBoxShadow: '0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75)',
    MozBoxShadow: '0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75)',
    boxShadow: '0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75)'
  }}>
    <div className='chat-header' style={{
      color: '#fff',
      backgroundColor: '#5ebe76',
      fontSize: '22px',
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      padding: '10px 15px'
    }}>
      <p>{props.supportName}</p>
    </div>
    <Messages
      defaultAdminUserName={props.defaultAdminUserName}
      contactName={props.contactName}
      messages={props.messages}
    />
    <Input
      visitSessionId={props.visitSessionId}
      onSend={props.onSend} />
  </div>
</div>

View.propTypes = {
  visitSessionId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  defaultAdminUserName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  contactName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  supportName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  messages: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  onSend: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default View
```

Here are some of the actions

`setChat.js`

```
import { SET_CHAT } from '.'

export default function (chat) {
  return {
    type: SET_CHAT,
    payload: chat
  }
}
```

`setContactId.js`

```
import { SET_CONTACT_ID } from '.'

export default function (contactId) {
  return {
    type: SET_CONTACT_ID,
    payload: contactId
  }
}
```

And here is the `submitMessage.js`, this is the only place I do dirty stuff.

```
import ddp from '../../../ddp'

export default function ({ message, visitSessionId }) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    ddp.call('chat.submitContactMessage', { message, visitSessionId, contactId: getState().contactId }).then((res) => {
      console.log('res', res)
    })
  }
}
```

This sends an update to my db. The db gets update. The subscription function in the container works fine. Getting the new document and setting it into the store with the `SET_CHAT` action. And in the devtools I can see the new chat in the store and as `Chat.jsx` props. However the `View.jsx` doesn't get the new props.

And here are the reducers `chatReducer.jsx`

```
import { SET_CHAT } from '../actions'

export default function (state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_CHAT:
      return action.payload
  }

  return state
}
```

`contactId.js`

```
import { SET_CONTACT_ID } from '../actions'

export default function (state = '', action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_CONTACT_ID:
      return action.payload
  }

  return state
}
```

and my `rootReducer`

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'

import contactId from './contactId'
import chatReducer from './chatReducer'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  contactId,
  chat: chatReducer
})

export default rootReducer
```

Comment: If the issue has to do with Mutations, you'll need to share your reducer(s) for review as that is where the mutations happen. Also be specific as to which items aren't updating. Lastly, I don't see any of the following functions which may be needed, shouldComponentUpdate(), componentDidUpdate(), or componentWillUpdate(). I'd start with should ComponentUpdate and go from there.

Comment: @SteveB I'll add reducers in a moment.
The `View.jsx` doesn't get the new `chat` prop.
And can you please elaborate on update functions. What do I need to do with them?

Comment: @SteveB I just tried to do some console logs in `componentDidUpdate` of `Chat.jsx` and it didn't log.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose `extractChatFromCollection` causes your mutation issue, try this :

```
  extractChatFromCollection = collection => {
    const chatId = Object.keys(collection)[0]
    const chat = {
      ...collection[chatId],
      _id: chatId,
    };
    return chat
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solved a similar problem in a React app that I've been struggling to make. I had to give my children components different "key" properties whenever my containers saw updated properties from Redux.

- Do your reducers correctly make copies of the state?
  See https://blog.jakoblind.no/react-component-not-updating/
- Will your children components accept "key" properties that will make them unique after each state change?